# WebAPI routing: single string parameter

Tags: c#, rest, http, asp.net-web-api

So, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api):

> - If the parameter is a “simple” type, Web API tries to get the value
>   from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int,
>   bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal,
>   and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from
>   a string. (More about type converters later.)
> - For complex types, Web
>   API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type
>   formatter.

I have a `POST` action with a single `string` parameter coming from the user's input and can therefore be any character - foreign, unicode, apostrophe, '%20' etc. anything!

I am therefore reluctant to have this parameter in the URL and the `[FromBody]` decorator doesn't appear to be helping. Question is: what is the best [*a-hem*] pratice for posting a single string parameter to WebAPI controller?

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/add")]
public void Add([FromBody]string name)
{
    // name is null :(
}
```

JS:

```
function add(name: string) {
    return this.$http.post("api/add/", name);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried to send simple string by post request without `[FromBody]` attribute from angular. I sent my value in request body. And it works. Can you check the request that it generates? (in browser or fiddler)

Comment: it was the lack of quote marks around the string value, which is just ridiculous!

Comment: fyi you didn't block out all of the instances of `/localhost/****/` in your image :p

Comment: @Tsar - is your problem solved?

Comment: If not, I have two possible solutions. 1) you can send the object within request payload (like { name : "my requested name" }) or 2) create and use custom attribute to take care about string in body without quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by wrapping the request object (name) in quotes, using [angular.toJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson)`:

```
function add(name: string) {
    return this.$http.post("api/add/", angular.toJson(name));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the `[FromBody]` decorator, you should consider creating a DTO so that Model binder can read the posted data from the request body and map to this DTO  object.

```
public class MyRequest
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/add")]
public void Add([FromBody]MyRequest model)
{
    //do something with model.Name
}
```

If you do not prefer to create a class, you can remove the [FromBody] decorator from your action method and keep a string type and send the value as querystring.

```
public void Add(string model)
{
    //do something with model.Name
}
```

and

```
$http.post('/api/add?name=Scott with a space')
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log('angular http response', response.data);
    })
```

Comment: that's exactly what i was trying to avoid doing

Comment: Pay the pain one time (e.g. make a generic `MyStringParameter` object) and then use it for as many api methods as you want.